# Can i have both ISession and IStatelessSession side by side?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, stateless

Consider a transaction-per-view model where with an `IHttpModule` i open a transaction using a standard `ISession`.

Now, i have a page where i want to do some batch operations. Since `IStatelessSession` is preferred for batch operations:

1. Can i have both `ISession` and `IStatelessSession` open at the same time? Is it safe?
2. If 1. yes can i use the same `ITransaction`?
3. If 2. no should i Commit & Close the `ISession` and its associated `ITransaction` and then open the `IStatelessSession` and a new `ITransaction` for it?
4. If 3. yes are there any pitfalls i should be aware of?

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes and yes.
2. No, each will have its own transaction.
3. I would commit the ISession's transaction but leave the ISession open.

I recommend not starting a transaction for every HTTP request. Instead start and commit a transaction on the page when you have changes to commit. This also improves exception handling because you can catch the exception on the page instead of at the end of the request.